# How to convert install/upgrade schema scripts to db_schema.xml files?

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3.1, setup, declarative-schema

I'm following the guide from [Magento DevDocs about the Declarative Schema](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/migration-commands.html)

I created a new module with old setup way (InstallSchema.php, InstallData.php) to test the convert install/upgrade schema scripts to `db_schema.xml` config. I ran two commands:

```
bin/magento setup:install --convert-old-scripts=1
bin/magento setup:upgrade --convert-old-scripts=1
```

But, I didn't see the `db_schema.xml` in my custom module. Why the `db_schema.xml` didn't generate in my module?

I also see the note from Magento

> The Schema Listener tool listens for schema changes and attempts to
>   change Magento code, so it should not be run in production mode. It is
>   disabled by default.

So, what should I do in my case? My app is in developer mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After writing my question. I found my issue: I had run the setup upgrade command before.

So, I removed my module from `setup_module` table and my custom data table. Then I ran the two commands again.

```
bin/magento setup:install --convert-old-scripts=1
bin/magento setup:upgrade --convert-old-scripts=1
```

Comment: which commands?

Comment: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. It's our "common" command. But, before that, we need to remove module from `setup_module`. @MohitRane

Comment: okay, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I removed from *setup_module* and also deleted the table second time. Didn't work at all. :(

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the following steps to successfully Migrate yours install/upgrade scripts to declarative schema

1. Go to your database search for **setup_module** table and delete all the modules for which you want to have **db_schema.xml**
2. Now Paste your module/s in the Vendor directory
   app\code\vendor\module
3. Then Give Permissions Required
4. Finally Convert your schema by pasting the following command

   **bin/magento setup:install --convert-old-scripts=1**
5. For further details please refer the link [Migrate install/upgrade scripts to declarative schema](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/migration-scripts/)

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 ` dear readers, please don't do this.